# How to drop string NULL values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, null

I have string 'NULL' values to drop. But I could not do it. Below is my data set and I need to drop row 1 and 4. How can I do that?
Thank you.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['NULL','x2','x3','x4],'B':['w1','w2','w3','NULL']})


     A     B
    NULL   w1
    x2     w2
    x3     w3
    x4     NULL
```

Thank you.

Comment: The rows are not null, they are strings. One is the string 'null' and other one is 'NULL'. I belive the dataframe is this:                                                df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[None,'x2','x3','x4'],'B':['w1','w2','w3',None]})

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) - to Test if pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series with `|` for OR bitwise.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['NULL','x2','x3','x4'],'B':['w1','w2','w3','NULL']})
m = df['A'].str.contains("NULL") | df['B'].str.contains("NULL")
df = df[~m]
print(df)

    A   B
1  x2  w2
2  x3  w3
```

OR

```
m = (df == 'NULL').any(1)
df = df[~m]
print(df)

    A   B
1  x2  w2
2  x3  w3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = df[(df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.lower()) != 'null').all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: @melik With the code you posted in the question (with 'NULL' / 'Null' / 'null' *strings*) it works fine. If your data has np.NaN values, it doesn't work, but then you should ask a different question.